# systemjs or browserify for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application which is developed in angularjs 1.x. Now I'm planning to convert it using John Papa angularjs style guide for future proofing my application upgrade to Angular 2. When going through Upgrading Angular 2 guide, it suggests [using a module loader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-a-module-loader). So which module loader is better for this SystemJS, Webpack, or Browserify. Please suggest and how to use it in my application.
Thanks in advance,
iijb

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum. Unfortunately, this question will probably get closed because it's too broad, too opinionated, and any answers given may become outdated. There are articles that already compare these 3 technologies; Read them, decide which one you think is best and try it. If you have issues with the process, then come back to SO with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to go with webpack as it is suggested by angular official website 
you can follow this link for setup https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html